# Parse HTML table using JSOUP and display it to listview

Tags: android, list, parsing, html-table, jsoup

I am new in **Android** programming. I need to get values from HTML and display it in list.
Here is link  http://www.hak.hr/info/cijene-goriva/

->so I need values (10,41,10.51)

```
<div id="div_eurosuper95">
                <table class="nowrapper fuel_segmented">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            Gorivo
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Cijena (kn)
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>

                    <tr>
                        <td class="fuel_name"><span class="vendorName">Tifon</span></br>euroSUPER 95 BS</td>
                        <td class="fuel_segmented">10,41</td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td class="fuel_name"><span class="vendorName">Tifon</span></br>EUROSUPER 95 
BS CLASS</td>
                        <td class="fuel_segmented">10,51</td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td class="fuel_name"><span class="vendorName">Crodux derivati</span></br>EUROSUPER 95 BS</td>
                        <td class="fuel_segmented">10,41</td>
                    </tr>


                    <tr>
                        <td class="fuel_name"><span class="vendorName">AdriaOil</span></br>Euro Super 95 BS TOP</td>
                        <td class="fuel_segmented">10,51</td>
                    </tr>

                </tbody>
            </table>
                </div>
```

Comment: are these numbers coming from a website in a XML or JSON format?? or just like these??

Comment: there is page source, so you can see it

Answer (score 1):

You can use Jsoup selector to select all the `<td>` tags that have are of class `fuel_segmented`.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
Elements fuel = doc.select("td.fuel_segmented");
```

This is a basic CSS selector syntax, where the `td` specifies the tag, and the `.` specifies that it is a class. If it was a specific `td` with an `id` you could've specified it as `td#fuel_segmented`.

This will return a collection of `Element` objects, represented by an `Elements` object.

To make it a bit more easy to see what is what, you can loop through the elements and display the corresponding fuel name.

```
Elements fuel = doc.select("td.fuel_segmented");
for (Element element : fuel) {
    System.out.println(element.previousElementSibling().text()
    + ": " + element.text());
}
```

which will output

```
Tifon euroSUPER 95 BS: 10,41
Tifon EUROSUPER 95 BS CLASS: 10,51
Crodux derivati EUROSUPER 95 BS: 10,41
AdriaOil Euro Super 95 BS TOP: 10,51
```

I suggest that you read more about how to use the selector in Jsoup to parse the data that you need. That part of the cookbook can be found [here.](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax)

Answer (score 0):

To display your datas in `ListView`, there is a [good tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/) to understand how does it work.

I really don't know where did you get these prices, on `Jsoup` you have all the ["Cookbooks"](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/dom-navigation) necessary, with examples to parse html document.